# Difference in SAS's proc mixed and R's lme4 (Standard Errors/Covariance Structure)

Tags: r, sas, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to replicate a model created in SAS using lme4 in R.

The SAS Model im using is;

```
proc mixed data=data2;
Class Antigen Subject_id;
Model Log2_HI_titer_Post = Antigen / ddfm=kr solution;
Repeated Antigen /  type=un Subject=Subject_id rcorr=2,4;
lsmeans Antigen / DIFF=CONTROL('controlantigen') alpha=.10 CL ;
run;
```

Which gives me solutions for the fixed effects as:

```
                                  Solution for Fixed Effects

                                                                             Standard
Effect         Antigen               Estimate       Error      DF    t Value    Pr > |t|

Intercept                             5.0719      0.3311      23      15.32      <.0001
Antigen        B/Brisbane/60/08      -0.8679      0.3193      23      -2.72      0.0123
Antigen        B/Brisbane/9/14       -1.8750      0.4096      23      -4.58      0.0001
```

In R I've used the model

```
fit <- with(SASdata2 , lmer(Log2_HI_titer_Post ~ 1 + Antigen + (1| subject_id )))
```

with output

```
Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 5.07190    0.34613  14.653
StrainB/Brisbane/60/08     -0.86792    0.41102  -2.112
StrainB/Brisbane/9/14      -1.87500    0.41102  -4.562
```

I believe the repeated Antigen in SAS is making each Strain get it's own S.E. whereas SAS is fitting them all together to find one overall S.E.?

How can I get lme4 to match SAS, I tried specifying the contrasts to match SAS with

```
options(contrasts = c(factor = "contr.SAS", ordered = "contr.SAS"))
```

but to no avail.

Edit; a snippet of the data:

```
  subject_id    Strain                Log2_HI_titer_Post
  AU_A_01       B/Brisbane/60/08      2.3219
  AU_A_02       B/Brisbane/60/08      2.3219
  AU_A_03       B/Brisbane/60/08      5.3219
  AU_A_04       B/Brisbane/60/08      4.3219
  AU_A_05       B/Brisbane/60/08      5.3219
  AU_A_06       B/Brisbane/60/08      2.3219
```

Comment: interesting.  The answers aren't *very* different; given that the fixed effects are identical, I think the actual models fitted are identical.  I think you'd have to look in a great deal of detail into the precise way that the standard errors are computed in SAS.  The relevant details about the standard error computation for `lme4` are at the bottom of p. 25 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823v1.pdf , but that might be more detail than you really wanted ...

Comment: you didn't specify the EMPIRICAL option for the standard errors without telling us, did you?

Comment: Specify them in SAS or R? I don't know how to i'm afraid. I will google to make sure i haven't.